# textbox's scroll bar is enable when shouldn't

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, scrollbar

I've created a textbox with a scrollbar that should always be enabled (on WORDWRAP!)
Of course, by default - it's enabled only when needed (text length > than the textbox's width).

For some reason, on one-liner textbox - the scrollbar always looks enabled (also when it's not needed).
It doesn't happen on multiline textbox.

Any idea why?

This is the code:

```
<TextBox x:Name="_textBox" Visibility="Visible" xml:space="preserve"
             Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},Path=Background}"
             Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},Path=Foreground}"
             FontFamily="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},Path=FontFamily}"
             BorderBrush="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},Path=BorderBrush}"
             KeyUp="_textBox_KeyUp"
             PreviewTextInput="_textBox_PreviewTextInput"
             DataObject.Pasting="_textBox_Pasting"
             VerticalContentAlignment="Top"
             PreviewKeyDown="TextBox_OnPreviewKeyDown"
             TextWrapping="Wrap"
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
             />
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` to `Visible` will ensure that the scroll bar is **always** visible, even if the content doesn't exceed the bounds.

Instead, set it to `Auto`, this will change the behaviour so that the scroll bar will only be visible when the content exceeds the bounds. (The text becomes too large for the `TextBox` to display)

Here is a very simply example:

```
<TextBox Text="..."
         TextWrapping="Wrap"
         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
```

By default, `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` is set to `Auto` anyway, so you can completely remove this line as it's not needed.

**TL;DR**

Remove `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"`.

Comment: Thanks, but as I mentioned above, I NEED the scrollbar to be always visible... The thing is, it's enabled only on one liner textbox